# NoSuchElementException rxjava

Tags: android, rxjava

Здравствуйте.
в приложении используется retrofit+rxjava.
После отправки запроса на сервер приходит 200 ответ, НО почему то rxjava выдает ошибку `NoSuchElementException rxjava`
Вот код

```
@Override
public Observable<Result> run(@NonNull Params params) {
    return RestClient
            .getInstance()
            .sendMessage(
                PreferencesController.getInstance().getToken(),
                params.getMessage(), 
                params.getEmail()
            ).map(result -> new Result())
            .toObservable();
}
```

Еще немного кода

```
addDisposable(
            test.run(new Test.Params(email.toString(),
                    message.toString()))                     
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> getViewState().showLoading(true))
                    .doOnTerminate(() -> getViewState().showLoading(false))
                    .onTerminateDetach()
                    .subscribe(result -> {                            
                    }, throwable -> {
                        if (throwable instanceof ValidationException) {
                            handleValidationException((ValidationException) throwable);
                        } else {

                            Timber.e(throwable, "error");
                        }
                    }));
```

Новая порция кода

```
 public Single<Void> sendMessage(@NonNull String accessToken, @NonNull String message, @NonNull String email) {
    return serverAPI.sendMessage(accessToken, new FeedbackRequest(message, email));
}
```

Вот полный лог

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
06-08 20:05:00.109 W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle$SingleElementObserver.onComplete(ObservableSingleSingle.java:113)
06-08 20:05:00.109 W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onComplete(BodyObservable.java:66)
06-08 20:05:00.110 W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallEnqueueObservable$CallCallback.onResponse(CallEnqueueObservable.java:61)
06-08 20:05:00.110 W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.callSuccess(OkHttpCall.java:132)
06-08 20:05:00.110 W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:111)
06-08 20:05:00.110 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
06-08 20:05:00.110 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
06-08 20:05:00.110 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
06-08 20:05:00.110 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
06-08 20:05:00.110 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

На сервер отправляется post запрос в заголовке токен, в теле запроса два параметра. При успешном запросе, сервер отвечает "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".Поэтому в retrofit прописал Single(Void), может из за этого ошибка возникает?
Подскажите что это за ошибка как ее устранить.

Comment: добавил код в первый пост

Comment: снова добавил код

Comment: там стандартная реализация retrofit для rxjava, и с запросом на сервер все в порядке, ведь ответ то приходит, причем успешный ответ, но вот не понятно почему rxjava выдает ошибку?

Comment: добавил код, в том то и дело что в стектрейсе нет ни одной ссылки на код, только на либы.

Comment: С большой долей уверенности могу подтвердить ваше предположение на счет Single<Void>. `subscribe` для него ждет ровно один элемент при  onComplete, а получает 0, от чего ему и плохеет

Comment: Вот похожий случай https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005866/observable-empty-causes-java-util-nosuchelementexception-sequence-contains-no
Автор пытался из `Empty` сделать `take(1)` с похожей ошибкой

Comment: огромное спс за помощь, завтра буду искать способы как модернизировать код, чтобы этой ошибки не возникало. помню что вроде бы есть какой то оператор который устанавливает кол-во ожидаемых элементов....(Типа: 0, 0 или 1, 1, 1 и более)

Comment: Да просто возвращайте что то и игнорируйте результат в `subscribe`. Либо попробуйте возвращать `Empty`, но тут не уверен, что корректно работать будет

Comment: перейдите на rxjava2 и используйте Completable вмсето Single<Void> либо поменять на Observable, чтобы  не вызывать toObservable()